# How do I group like data returned from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I created a list in sharepoint gathering user information.  Each entry has date.  Some days have many entries.  My goal is to create a select menu that has the dates.  When I click the menu the dates populate but they repeat.  How do I return them as a single value?

I've tried to nest another for loop and an if statement.

```
$.ajax({
   url:url,
   method:'GET',
   headers:{ 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose' },
   success: function(data){
     var dat = data.d.results;
      for (var i = 0;i < dat.length; i++){
    html+='<optionvalue='+itm.dateVal+'>'+itm.dateVal+'</option>';
       }     $('#week-selector').append(html);
   },
   error: function(e){
    console.log('error:'+e);
   }            
});
```

**The output I am getting is:**

```
3/3/2019
3/3/2019
3/3/2019
3/3/2019
3/6/2019
3/6/2019
3/10/2019
3/10/2019
```

**The output I want to get is:**

```
3/3/2019
3/6/2019
3/10/2019
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicated question of : [remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write a filter function to get distinct values.

```js
var arr = [
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/6/2019",
"3/6/2019",
"3/10/2019",
"3/10/2019"
];


var distinctDates = arr.filter(function(val, idx, self){ return self.indexOf(val) === idx; });

console.log(distinctDates);
```

in ES6 you can do it the following way

```js
var arr = [
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/3/2019",
"3/6/2019",
"3/6/2019",
"3/10/2019",
"3/10/2019"
];


var distinctDates = [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(distinctDates);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicate values using a Set and then converting it back to an array:

````
var arr = [
    "3/3/2019",
    "3/3/2019",
    "3/3/2019",
    "3/3/2019",
    "3/6/2019",
    "3/6/2019",
    "3/10/2019",
    "3/10/2019"
];

console.log(Array.from(new Set(arr)));
// ["3/3/2019", "3/6/2019", "3/10/2019"]```
````

Answer (score 0):

var arr = ['3/3/2019', '3/3/2019', '4/4/2019']

arr.filter(function(item, i){ return arr.indexOf(item) == i;})